# How to convert an ECDSA secp256k1 PEM formatted private key to binary?

Tags: security, openssl, ecdsa, amazon-kms, secp256k1

I am trying to import my secp256k1 private key into AWS KMS. My key is PEM formatted and AWS KMS says *'The key material must be in binary format'* . How do I go about converting my ECDSA secp256k1 PEM formatted private key to binary?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is this of any relevance? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/importing-keys-encrypt-key-material.html

Comment: Thanks @AntonKrug, I was following the same guide but it doesn't have any instructions on how to convert an existing pem key to binary. However, I found the solution and will post it as an answer for better visibility for others.

Comment: Great you found the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

For others who are looking, found this on GCP.

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -inform PEM -outform DER \
    -in /path/to/asymmetric-key-pem \
    -out /path/to/formatted-key
```